# Error:Unknown host 'dl.google.com' You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error in android studio 3.0.

> Unknown host 'dl.google.com' You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle

I have checked my auto proxy option already.

[image]

Comment: select first option enable gradle

Comment: pl, check your internet connection first.

Answer (score 61):

I was also having the same problem. I tried the following and it's working for me:

**Windows**

Go to : *File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy* [Under IDE Settings] *Enable following option Auto-detect proxy settings*

**Mac**

Go to : *Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behavior*.. etc

You can also use the test connection button and check with google.com to see if it works or not.

Comment: Auto-detect proxy settings option is already enabled, still I am getting same error.

Comment: Download a recent gradle release from gradle.org/releases Unzip the file and copy the gradle folder e.g. gradle 4.0 into C -- program files -- android -- android studio -- gradle. On your android studio goto file -- settings -- Build, Execution, Deployment --Build Tools -- Gradle and choose Use local gradle distribution, in the gradle home locate your gradle folder and click apply. Then click okay.  Your android studio might require a more recent gradle release, make sure you download a gradle that is compatible with your studio or latest release

Answer (score 30):

In my case this worked:

*File>invalid caches/restart >invalid and restart*

Answer (score 23):

Also, check the internet connection and try again clean and build it's worked for me.

Comment: This. Make sure you're connected to the internet.

Answer (score 8):

The issue is reproduced on Android Studio 2020.3.1
Arch linux
Gradle 7.2
JDK 11

Fixed by setting HTTP Proxy as on the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Your system needs to be online at the time you are building the project first time for the dependencies you have added. Dependencies are downloaded from the google and jcenter servers. After you build the project then you don't need internet connection because dependencies will be available offline.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me

Comment: yeah that process is important... especially for new comers.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, it happens due to the internet not being connected or the internet speed is too slow. Just check the internet connection and run again.

Answer (score 3):

This problem usually occurs when we change your project from one pc to another . the proxy of the system is disabled and the solution that worked for me is :
File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy [Under IDE Settings] Enable following option Auto-detect proxy settings

Comment: Perfect solution when work from virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to reconnect your phone with android studio and then install or run your program

Comment: This could have easily been a comment... Please explain what seems to be the issue and why this would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when u add some new dependencies you require an internet connection to download the dependencies from the internet. By default the Android Studio as set the option to connecting to the internet to get a proper flow. But if u cant connect to the internet, work with the gradle in offline mode and later when the internet comes again...it will automatically download the necessary files in background!

Solution:
    Click on Enable gradle offline mode and sync the project!

Answer (score 1):

This error appears if its have not compatible versions of Android Gradle plugin and Gradle wrapper. This versions works for me:

`project_dir/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1')
    }
}
```

`project_dir/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Answer (score 1):

please check your gradle wrapper, there are 2 gradle wrapper, one is in library folder, and one is in gradle folder. probably the version of both gradle wrapper is different. i solve my case by make them as a same version..

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error even after trying every possible combination of proxy settings, invalidate cache and restart.

The error vanished as soon as I switched my internet connection from wifi to mobile hotspot. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

error message:

### Unknown host '**No such host** is known (jitpack.io)'. You may need to **adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.**

This means that you are **using a dependency** that **requires** an **internet connection** to find the **repository** where the library is.

in your **build.gradle file**   //**must be** url "host" **repository  is exists**. example

> ```
> repositories {  maven { url "https://jitpack.io"  }
> ```

### **resolve:**

1. Go To: File -->Appearance & Behavior > System Setting > HTTP Proxy > set radius as Auto-detect proxy settings.
2. Connect to Internet   and check connection is true or not.
3. Run App

Answer (score 0):

Restarting emulator worked for me.

Comment: What does the emulator have in common with Gradle Sync?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after I config kotlin for project I face this problem.

After 30 minutes try 'Auto proxy' and learn about proxy with no hope, I see suddenly I see

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

in the end of my `build.gradle`. Then I delete it and it working.
The most interesting is after it working, I put above line to `gradle` again but it still working.
So maybe it is not a root problem, however I think it may bring some luck in some case.

Currently, I use `Window` and `AndroidStudio 3.4.2`

Answer (score 0):

In current android studio 3.5, 
simply go to file -> Setting, 
search "HTTP" in search bar, 
Enable Auto-detect proxy settings, 
click Ok to make the changes effective.

Answer (score 0):

update classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1' in gradle file of project and
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip to latest. in gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 0):

When it stuck with such error on my CI (looks like build got cached), I had to just push smth to re-run build

Answer (score -1):

My case was resolved by changing the IP and using the VPN. Because firebase.google.com did not load for me.
The problem was solved when the website loaded for me and I rebuilt it.