# android studio error" Could not download builder.jar"

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to run my first "hello world" program on android studio 3.4.2 but, but it failed. the error is "Gradle issue... Could not download builder.jar, no cache available for offline mode".

Answer (score 0):

as the error description says, " No cached version available for offline mode", so you need to turn on gradle and rebuild application, in order to do this:

> File-->Settings -->Build, Executions, Deployment --> Build Tools --> Gradle --> uncheck the "offline work" --> click on the apply button --> rebuild your application

Comment: i have tried doing that, but  i still get that error!

Comment: Unknown host 'dl.google.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Comment: Try this, go to `File>invalid caches/restart >invalid and restart`

Comment: And Ive seen this error in stack please see the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688811/errorunknown-host-dl-google-com-you-may-need-to-adjust-the-proxy-settings-in