# Connect to google fails when first build blank Android application

Tags: android, android-studio

I just download the latest version of Android Studio(3.6.2) and want to try the blank application with my phone.

When the blank application going to build, the error pops up as:

**> Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/203.208.46.146, dl.google.com/2404:6800:4005:80f:0:0:0:200e] failed: No route to host (connect failed)**

Because of this failure, it shows that I could not get resource of grade-3.6.2.pom.

I am using Java 1.8 and I am sure I have network connected. Does anyone face the same situation and have some ideas about it? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Check for the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688811/errorunknown-host-dl-google-com-you-may-need-to-adjust-the-proxy-settings-in) , maybe it will help!