# getting error Unknown host 'dl.google.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.in android 4.02

Tags: android

Recently I have installed Android 4.02 in new PC.
I am getting error `Unknown host 'dl.google.com. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle`
I have tried settings of http for *no proxy* and *proxy* both. And checked connections it is ok.
On enabling offline
getting error:

`No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 available for offline mode. Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project`

**One observation**:
It is able to download gradle distribution files but when it starts sync...while downloading .pom  files it gives this error for new project.

I have tried
[Error:Unknown host 'dl.google.com' You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688811/errorunknown-host-dl-google-com-you-may-need-to-adjust-the-proxy-settings-in)
still unable to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Gradle manually.
The latest release can be found at gradle.org/releases.
After downloading unzip the file and copy the gradle folder e.g. gradle 4.0 into C -- program files -- android -- android studio -- gradle.
In your android studio goto file -- settings -- Build, Execution, Deployment --Build Tools -- Gradle and choose Use local gradle distribution, in the gradle home locate your gradle folder and click apply.
Save the new settings, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i had installed android in F drive. In gradle home user i had F:/softwares/android/setup/gradle/gradle-6.6.1 and i had tried both options for use gradle from : 1.F:/softwares/android/setup/gradle/gradle-6.6.1 and 2. gradle  wrapper properties file". It is downloading istributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip but as soon as gradle daemon starts it gives above error whie downloading .pom file  I had also tried same with installation in C drive

Comment: also getting Please ensure the host name is correct. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle. Ihad tried no proxy and auto proxy. Still same error

Comment: After the manual download and setup, make sure you run in offline mode.

Comment: yes , in that case getting errorL; No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 available for offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

try set dns from `shecan.ir` website . in iran it works like charm .

Answer (score 0):

build>clean and re-build the project, it's worked for me.