# Android Emulator in android studio running but not showing App

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I am very new to Kotlin and Android studio. I tried running my App through the emulator, I built in AVD manager.
Whenever I run my App it goes to the home screen, I don't know what you'll need to solve this or what causes it:

[image: Here's a screenshot of the emulator]

But based on what I've seen as I researched this issue, here are some info I think you might need;

-I've turned off `detect adb location` and set the directory to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

-`minimumSdk 21`

-`targetSdk 31`

-My `Api level` is 25

Please whatever info you need to help me rectify this issue just ask me..

I am open to any suggestions, Thank you in advance for your help!

here's a screenshot of build error:

[image]

I'm adding a logcat error message screenshot, though they are much of error I just screen the ones that could be taken on a single shot, I hope it enough.

[image]

(Please note that previously my logcat was empty even when I was experiencing the same problem, so I created another emulator, and the logcat is no longer empty..)

Comment: Do you have any code in your app?  You can open logcat and see logs.

Comment: Sounds like you're crashing, or you didn't build/install properly.

Comment: may be it is crashing while you run app on emulator. Check logs.

Comment: @JeenbekKhydyr I'm really  new what should I look for the logcat

Comment: @GabeSechan I don't have much in the mainactivity.kt file, What I have there should only return Hello World and a button, could you please elaborate what you mean my I didn't build properly??

Comment: @Aris_choice What should be looking out for in the Logcats..

Comment: On the bottom of android studio you can find logcat, if you open it you can see errors saying what went wrong

Comment: @Edwin you can find out what's crashing your app in logs. And you can fix that accordingly either attach screenshot of logs.

Comment: @JeenbekKhydyr I've added a screenshot of the logcat error message, though there a bunch of them I just screenshot the ones I could on one shot.. Please I'd like if you could take a look at it, and tell me what you think..

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688884/13885374

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the logcat to be able to see what went wrong.

Comment: @Aris_choice I've added a screenshot of build error, for some reason logcat is empty.. right now I'm trying to use my phone to run it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).